# Confused with a limit problem.

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\big((n+1)(n+1)(n+3)......3n\big)^{1/n}}{(n^{2n})^{1/n}}= ?$$

Comment: So, essentially, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \frac{(3n)!}{n!(n^{2n})} \right]^{1/n}$?  Have you considered using Stirling?  (I haven't looked at this closely, but I would guess it would answer this...)

Comment: Show you working, why are you stuck?

Comment: i need the answer in the form e^x. What's Stirling? @BrianTung

Comment: Here's the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) on it.

Comment: thanks. But what's the answer to the above question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ((n+1)(n+2)\cdots(3n))^{1/n} /n^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ((3n)!/n!)^{1/n}/n^2$

By Stirling's approximation, this becomes $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt{6 \pi n} (3n/e)^{3n} / (\sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n))^{1/n} / n^2$ which can be simplified to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (27^n\sqrt{3} (n/e)^{2n})^{1/n} / n^2 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 27\cdot3^{1/2n}\cdot (n/e)^{2} / n^2 = 27/e^2$.

And here's some numerical verification https://ideone.com/hwHyVI

Comment: I am unaware of Stirling's approximation. Is there any simpler method? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

(No Stirling's approx.)

> **Result:** If $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{1/n}=l.$

So all we need to find is just limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$

Now given $a_n=\frac{(3n)!}{n!n^{2n}}$ so $a_{n+1}=\frac{(3(n+1))!}{(n
+1)!(n+1)^{2(n+1)}}$. So $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(3(n+1))! n!n^{2n}}{(n+1)!(n+1)^{2(n+1)}(3n)!}\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3(n+1)(3n+2)(3n+1)n^{2n}}{(n+1)^3(n+1)^{2n}}\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n}\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3(3+\frac{2}{n})(3+\frac{1}{n})}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^2}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n}=\frac{27}{e^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

May be you don't need any approximation for this question. You can do it directly.

First, take ln both the sides and arrange it in this way $$lnL=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{\ln(i+n)}{n}-\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{\ln(n)}{n})$$
I have arranged the second term in form of a summation. Now combine both of the summations $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{\ln(\frac{i}{n}+1)}{n}$$. Now assume $\frac{i}{n}$ as $t$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ as $dt$ . So now this limits is converted to a integration $$lnL=\int_{t=0}^2 ln(1+t)dt$$ Limits are decided by $t=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{i}{n})$ . Put the values of $i=1$ to $i=2n$, you will get the limits. So now integration is $lnL=\int_{t=1}^3 ln(t)dt=3ln3-2$ which means $$L=\frac{27}{e^2}$$ Final answer without any approximation.

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as other answers and comments, let us consider $$A_n= \left[ \frac{(3n)!}{n!(n^{2n})} \right]^{1/n}$$ Taking logarithms $$\log(A_n)=\frac 1 n\left(\log(3n!)-\log(n!)-2n\log(n) \right)$$ Now, using Stirling approximation $$\log(k!)\sim k\log\left(\frac k e\right)+\frac 12 \left(\log(k)+\log(2\pi)\right)$$ Replacing, expanding the logarithms and simplifying leads to $$\log(A_n)\sim \frac 1 n\left( n (\log (27)-2)+\frac{\log (3)}{2}\right)=\log (27)-2+\frac{\log (3)}{2 n}=\log\left(\frac{27}{e^2}\right)+\frac{\log (3)}{2 n}$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.